# How to customize the process of webpack compiling .vues file to .js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am new to webpack plugins and I understand that there's this **html-webpack-plugin** that allows users to customize the process of webpack generating html files.

Similarly I am trying to find a plugin for .vue files, that allows me to have access to the .vue files at the process of webpack trying to load them into .js files. (I may need to do some global modifications to .vue files before they are converted.)

Where do I start looking ? Is there already a plugin that serves the purpose ? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

guess you want get source code of vue files before converting to js, you can custom a loader to process .vue files before they got changed in vue-loader.